# O que significa "Tree-Shaking"?

Tags: terminologia, typescript, ecmascript-6

Eu acompanho de perto todo o desenvolvimento do Angular. Sei que a terceira geração do motor de renderização (o [Ivy](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21706), codinome para o Render 3) será lançada logo.

No geral, os objetivos para esse novo renderer são:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode-se ver no diagrama acima, uma das promessas deste novo motor é a redução do *bundle size*, e pelo que eu entendi a técnica usada para essa redução é o "Tree-Shaking".

O que exatamente o Tree-Shaking faz?

Como ele pode ser usado em outros projetos TypeScript? (pelo que eu li há uma correlação entre TypeScript e esta técnica)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Na verdade em geral se aplica a JavaScript, ou mais precisamente à geração de código JavaScript "otimizado". O código original pode estar em TypeScript, JavaScript mesmo, ou outra linguagem. Segundo a Wikipedia o conceito [surgiu no contexto do LISP, nos anos 1990](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.lisp/pspFr1XByZk), mas se trata da solução para um problema comum em linguagens dinâmicas. É bem provável que o conceito seja mais antigo do que essa troca de mensagens na Usenet.

O nome vem da ideia de chacoalhar uma árvore (tradução de *tree shaking*) para derrubar as frutas podres e as folhas mortas. Em programação é uma metáfora para eliminação de código morto, que existe em seu projeto mas não é utilizado na prática. Pense no monte de tralha que o `npm` e outros incluem na sua base de código.

A metáfora é a de uma árvore porque isso é feito construindo a árvore de dependências do seu código, que diz qual módulo/arquivo depende de quais outros. Geralmente o algoritmo de tree shaking vai percorrer seu código a partir de um ou mais pontos de entrada (arquivos), e marcar os outros arquivos que vão sendo citados por `import`, montando uma árvore com os módulos efetivamente utilizados no código.

#### Referências (em inglês)

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_shaking)
- [Google Developers - Reduce JavaScript Payloads with Tree Shaking](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-javascript/tree-shaking/)
- [Dr. Axel Rauschmayer, Exploring ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/). [16.8.2.1 Benefit: dead code elimination during bundling](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_benefit-dead-code-elimination-during-bundling)