# Imports parciais trazem vantagens para a aplicação?

Tags: desempenho, dart, import

Algumas linguagens trazem como recurso a importação de partes da biblioteca utilizada.

Utilizando Dart como exemplo temos dois tipos de imports parcial `show`e `hide` .

`import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart' show LatLng;`

*Importa somente a classe LatLng da biblioteca.*

`import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart' hide LatLng;`

*Importa todas as classe da biblioteca menos a LatLng.*

Nesse contexto, importar somente as classe que serão utilizadas de uma biblioteca traz alguma vantagem para aplicação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para a aplicação em si não traz vantagens, especialmente de desempenho, mas para a legibilidade do seu código depende, você pode considerar que tem vantagem sim, ou não.

Quando importa só que vai usar o *namespace* fica mais limpo e não corre o risco de algo conflitar com outra cosia que estaria em outro lugar. Ao mesmo tempo um IDE não mostrará algumas coisas que poderia usar se tivesse importado tudo e te ajudar usar alguma coisa que não tinha pensado.

Obviamente esconder só um tipo ajuda menos, mas pode ser só o que deseja mesmo, pode ser que saiba que só aquilo entraria em conflito.

E se tiver que importar muitos tipos pode ficar mais confuso ainda, então a maior vantagem é quando tem que importar apenas um tipo daquela biblioteca.

É possível que em algumas situações tenha algum ganho mínimo no tempo de compilação, mas nada que importe, é muito mínimo mesmo, só para constar, não é que grandes porções de código deixarão de ser compiladas. O ganho de tempo de compilação que eu falo é porque é mais fácil administrar os símbolos quando há menos deles, por isso é mínimo.

O *tree-shaking* ajuda a aplicação Dart ter vantagens porque haverá bem menos carga e pelo menos em algum aspecto haverá ganho de performance, mas não por causa do `import`. [A técnica de *tree-shaking* nada tem a ver com a técnica de importação falada aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57631384/221800), inclusive o *link* inicial da outra resposta fala sobre isso, basta ler com atenção. O *tree-shaking* fará algo não ser compilado desde que aquilo não seja usado pelo código, mas o fato de não importar algo não significa que não há uso na aplicação.

Answer (score 3):

Olhando do ponto de vista de performance, utilizar o `show/hide`não implica [necessariamente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26191878/10746978) em uma melhoria.

Isto é, apesar de você dizer ao compilador que seu código usará apenas uma classe específica, pode ser que essa classe importada faça uso internamente de outras partes da biblioteca. No final, tudo será compilado.

Consequentemente, em linguagens que façam uso de [tree-shaking](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/317837/o-que-significa-tree-shaking), que é o caso de Dart usado como exemplo em sua pergunta, isso não acarreta diferença no tempo de compilação ou no tamanho do aplicativo gerado.

Uma das ajudas que tais palavras reservadas trazem é a redução de conflitos de nome: Se você importa apenas X, e não Y e Z, pode nomear suas classes de Y e Z sem nenhum problema. Pelo mesmo motivo, sua IDE não irá sugerir ou tentar auto-completar coisas que não dizem respeito ao seu interesse.

Outro exemplo de ajuda para o programador é para deixar **claras** suas intenções ao fazer um import. Quem ler aquele import depois vai saber que aquele código utiliza apenas tal classe, e já vai poder ter um entendimento melhor de seu uso.